# Solving a DAE (differential algebraic equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, reduction-of-order-ode

I'm interested in differential algebraic equations. [https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/solve-differential-algebraic-equations-daes.html]

I have this one:

> $$y_1'(t)=-y_2(t)$$
>
> $$0=y_1(t)-(\frac{y_2^3(t)}{3}-y_2(t))$$

I've called $y_1=y(t)$, and $y(2)=y'(t)$, and then I differentiated both the equations, and got

> $$y_1'=y_2^2 y_2' - y_2'$$
>
> $$y_2'=-y_2''-y_2y_2''-2y_2y_2'^2$$

Now, if $y_3=y_2'$, then $y_3'=y_2''$ and  the system becomes:

> $$y_1'=y_2^2 y_3 - y_3$$
>
> $$y_2'=y_3$$
>
> $$y_3'=\frac{-2y_2y_3 - y_3}{1+y_2}$$

Is my resolution right?  And most of all, is this the correct way to proceed?

Comment: There are some mistakes Feddy $$y_2'=-y_2''-y_2y_2''-2y_2y_2'^2$$  should have an exponent 2

Comment: sorry but can't see why it should have an exponent 2...

Comment: You differentiate and have an exponent 2 in the function you differentiate so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to differentiate the second equation once and then isolate $y_2'$ from both equations to get 
$$
y_2'=\frac{y_2}{1-y_2^2}.
$$
This is now an isolated scalar ODE that can be solved by separation.

Answer (score 0):

You first equation says $y_1(t) = -y_2(t)$. This implies for the second equation:
$$ 0 = y_1(t) -(y_2(t)^3/3 - y_2(t)) = y_1(t)+y_2(t) -y_2(t)^3/3 = y_2(t)^3/3. $$
From this, it follows that $y_2(t) = 0$ and therefore also $y_1(t) = 0$.

Comment: sorry, there was a mistake, Just edited my question